# Get CS:GO Inventory from Steam API for my React APP

Tags: reactjs, steam-web-api

Since requesting the Inventory from https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v1/ is permanently disabled I have to use https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<steam_id>/inventory/json/2

Because of CORS I have to use my backend to provide the requested data. But when I do requests too often, my requests get rejected and my app cannot work on a large scale.

So the question should be simple: How can I avoid the rejection of my requests?
Any ideas and suggestions welcome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam inventory endpoints are pretty heavily rate-limited, but there are a few different endpoints that you can use.

**Trade offer endpoint**
https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/partnerinventory
This is the endpoint that's used when you open a trade offer with someone. It can be used to fetch both your own inventory as well as a trade partners. Required parameters are `partner` which is the user's Steam 64 Id, `appid` which is 730 in the case of CS:GO, and `contextid` which is 2 for most valve games. I don't know the exact limit, but I've been hitting this endpoint about once a second for a month with minimal 429 responses. To use this endpoint, you need to have a valid steam session and send the proper cookies along with the request. This will also only return tradable items.

**Inventory endpoint #1**
http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/STEAM64ID/APPID/CONTEXTID
Another inventory endpoint which has the same parameters but in the URL. I use this endpoint as a fallback to the first, but I've found that if the first endpoint is rate limited then this one will be too. That said, this one becomes limited much faster so it's best to use the first one instead.

**Inventory endpoint #2**
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/STEAM64ID/inventory/json/APPID/CONTEXTID
The endpoint you're using. I don't use this one at all, but it could be worth knowing as another fallback.

Not all of them return the same data format, so be mindful. One inventory a second is a pretty solid rate for any decently sized site, especially if you limit user's ability to refresh inventories. If you need more though, you'll have to start looking into proxies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! To lower request rates I'll probably use caching and limit the amount of refreshes for the user.