# Steam get inventory of user returns 429 after few requests

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I need to obtain a users csgo-steam-inventory by a given steamId via this endpoint:

`https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/<STEAMID64>/730/2?l=english&count=5000`

This has worked well for some time, but recently, I feel like there has been a massive increase in rate-limitation, because now, even when trying in the browser, if I reload the page 5 times each time with 1-2 seconds pause inbetween, i soon get a ´429 Too many requests´.

Is there any way to avoid this, or is there a way by using existing libraries?

I have tried using proxies (public ones, which might have been blacklisted i guess), but this does not work properly. I still get `429`ed. What would the proper way to do this via proxies, if not using public ones? Buying multiple servers with different IP's is too expensive.

I also tried increasing the delay between requests up to 5 seconds, but still I get blocked.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, and also based on personal experience, the delay between requests varies from 2 minutes and above.
if the limit is exceeded, your outgoing requests may be blocked for 12 hours.
Perhaps you can reduce the timeout in your requests by reducing the number of requested items ( [Similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76047820/how-am-i-exceeding-steam-apis-rate-limit) )

For myself personally, I still see a way out in private proxies
Many private proxies that change when we make a new request
But this is certainly not the most optimal and best way.
Perhaps third party APIs can help you ( [example](https://steamapis.com) ) or other way to parse inventory ( [like in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69620113/get-csgo-inventory-from-steam-api-for-my-react-app) )